# Shifting Sequences Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I'm reading the book 
[Vinay Ingle, John Proakis - Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB® (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.ca/Digital-Signal-Processing-Using-MATLAB%C2%AE/dp/1111427372/ref=sr_1_sc_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1404882340&sr=8-2-spell&keywords=signal%20processing%20using%20matalb) and I came across a function to shift sequences. Mathematically,

$$
y(n) = \{x(n-k) \}
$$

if $m = n-k$, then 
$$
y(m+k) = \{ x(m) \}
$$

```
function [y,n] = sigshift(x,m,k)
n = m + k;
y = x;
end
```

This function shifts nothing. I've tried to find errata list of the book, but I couldn't find it. Is this function correct?

Comment: I'd comment that the function is available at - https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2189.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function just changes the x-axis for plotting signals. It's indeed pretty trivial but the idea is to use it like this:

```
n = 0:4;
x = [1 2 3 2 1];           % some signal
[y,m] = sigshift(x,n,3);   % shift to the right by 3 samples
subplot(2,1,1), stem(n,x)
subplot(2,1,2), stem(m,y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to shift in MATLAB you need to play with the indices of the signal vector.
for example, given vector x - `vX` of length `L`, to shift it in time such that the first sample is the fifth you'll do this:

```
vXShifted = x(5:L);
```

Pay attention that the signal is shorter by 4 samples.

Now, sometimes, for periodic signals, a cyclic shifting is required which can be done using [`circshift()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of discrete signal processing applications, one uses a circular shift, ie samples on the right are moved circularly to the left (or the converse). In practice, one can handle a standard shift via signal padding and consistent windowing, followed by circular shifts. Matlab has a built-in [`circshift.m`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) function. An example os use is given below:

```
lData = 128;
lag = 13;
data = rand(lData,1).*window(@hamming,lData);
dataShift = circshift(data,lag);
plot(linspace(0,lData-1,lData),[data,dataShift]);
grid on; legend('Data','Data shifted');axis tight
```

[image: Circular shift of a windowed signal]