# Shift vector function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am working on my own shift vector function that will be used later to compute the convolution of two signals. The function has to shift the vectors either left or right depending on the magnitude and direction of the shift value. My code is:

```
%This function shifts a vector either left or right

function sv = shiftvector(v, n) %Where v is the vector and
                                %n is the shift value
vnew = zeros(1,length(v));

for i = 1:length(v)-n

if n>0

vnew(i) = v(i+n);

elseif n<0

    vnew(i+1:end) = v(1:end-n);

end

end
sv = vnew;
end
```

The issue I have is, whenever I input a negative shift value, MATLAB gives an error. Need help!

Comment: How about using $circshift()$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not accept lesser than $1$ indices. Other languages often accept a $0$-based index. More about [Shifting Sequences Using MATLAB](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/shifting-sequences-using-matlab/61001#61001) is available, including function `circshift.m`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Oh by the way, is shifting a vector similar to performing adding/subtracting the shift value on the original vector?

Comment: How do you define ' adding/subtracting the shift value'  adding/subtracting the shift value

Answer (score 1):

You must understand an important indexing issue when simulating algorithms using computers. In particular **linear** shifting, as negative indices do not exist. You cannot arbitrarily shift a vector to left or right without before adjusting the frame/window/block size.

Consider the following signal :

$$ x[n] = \{7,9,0,4,8\} $$

It has five nonzero samples for the time indices $n = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Its Matlab representation can be with the following vector / matrix:

```
xv = [7,9,0,4,8]
```

Here the time-index of the first vector-sample "7" is an **implied** zero. (and it's actually **one** wrt the array/matrix indexing). In other words $$ x_v(1) = x[0] $$

When you shift this sequence to left, by one sample to obtain $y[n] = x[n+1]$, then its beginning sample "7" will now have an index of $n=-1$, which you cannot have in Matlab (or any other computer language). What you can do is to simulate this in a roundabout way; i.e., create a large enough observation frame length say $n \in \{-L,L \}$ for some integer  $L$, then assign the sequence time-index **$0$** to the matlab-vector index $i=L+1$. This will work as long as your sequence lengths + shifts are shorter than window length.

Similar problem occurs for right shifts which can be avoided by enlarging the output vector that holds the shifted seqeunce.

The following is an example implementation of the idea :

```
% simulates LINEAR shift of vectors using a frame length
clc; clear all; close all;

L = 32;         % symmetric time frame [-L,L]
n = [-L:L];     % time index for plotting
N = length(n);  % length of the frame

ind0 = L+1;     % time-index 0 is at matlab index ind0

x = zeros(1,N); % row-vector to hold the sequence x[n]
x(ind0:ind0+4) = [7,9,-3,2,5];



% SHIFT FUNCTION:
d = 7;          % y[n] = x[n-d];
y = zeros(1,N);

if (d > L+1) | (d < -L-length(x))
    error('shift out of window range...');
elseif d >= 0
    y(d+1:end) = x(1:end-d);   
else % d < 0
    y(1:end+d) = x(-d+1:end);   
end


% DISPLAY:
figure,stem(n,x);
title('x[n]');

figure,stem(n,y);
title(['y[n] = x[n-d] for d = ',num2str(d)]);
```